# Discord.py Warning command

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to work on a warning command, and I was wondering if you could help me with it, I am trying to make it so that once I warn someone, it disposes it to a .json file, my code is as below:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def warn(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, arg):
    logsChannel = bot.get_channel(839235810200780800)
    user = member.mention
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Warning issued: ", color=0xf40000)
    embed.add_field(name="Warning: ", value=f'Reason: {arg}', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="User warned: ", value=f'{member.mention}', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Warned by: ", value=f'{ctx.author}', inline=False)

    embed2 = discord.Embed(title="Warning issued: ", color=0xf40000)
    embed2.add_field(name="Warning: ", value=f'Reason: {arg}', inline=False)
    embed2.add_field(name="User warned: ", value=f'{member.mention}', inline=False)
    embed2.add_field(name="Warned by: ", value=f'{ctx.author}', inline=False)

    await logsChannel.send(embed=embed2)
    await member.send(f'You have been warned in Jackkkks Society for **{arg}**!')
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: StackOverflow community won't write code for you, just type *python json tutorial* in yours browsers searchbar and learn it by yourself. If you encounter a problem then ask a question.

Comment: You have to give us a bit more code/information and what you have tried so far

Comment: You should not be using json for this kind of stuff. If you want to follow a json format then go with mongodb either pymongo or motor. You can also use mysql/postgresql. As mentioned by lolo, we won't write code for you.

Comment: The question will be closed, next time try to be more clear about you trying to do and add all the code necessary to help you

Answer (score 0):

First you would have to import the json module

```py
import json
```

Then under your embed or wherever as long as it is in that command indent, do this:

```py
with open("warns.json", "r") as f: # Set the warns.json to the name of the file
        warns_list = json.load(f)
warns_list[str(member.id)] = arg
with open("warns.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(warns_list, f, indent=4)
```

I think this should work, I don't want to spoon feed you, so just find a way of opening the json file to recieve the data